# Will dropping out of a masters make it harder to get accepted to a masters in another field?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, application

I'm first year master's student in Iran, but I'm not happy with my field and my university. I want to apply for a new master's program in field of my interest and in europe, say Germany for example. To do that I have to drop my current education. But I worry that dropping my current master's would have bad effects on my application for new master's program. Any idea what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is very specific to you and not a good fit for this site. Can you edit it to be more general? For example, "Is dropping out of one Masters program to pursue another perceived poorly on applications?"

Comment: Your major concern (that _we_ can advise you on, anyway) seems to be "I worry that dropping my current master's would have bad effects on my application for new master's program." Perhaps you can [edit] your post to focus on that aspect, i.e. ask "Will dropping out of a masters make it harder to get accepted to a masters in another field?"

Answer (score 1):

I can only say this with all of my heart:

**Above all else, choose a field that maximizes both your earning potential and your love for the occupation.**

In that statement, I've narrowed it down to two variables. You can make it more complicated if you choose, but I'd advise against it. Trust me. 25 years from now, you don't want to regret having chosen the wrong occupation. I can't stress that enough. Look at this [resource](http://www.bls.gov/ooh/) regarding occupations.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But my question is, whether I should tell the application office about my master's program that I did drop, or not?

Comment: @HoldenCLF If they don't ask you, then you don't need to tell them. If they do ask, then it's best to be truthful because you don't want to be considered unethical for lying. Also, it's your money. If you don't think you're getting your money's worth, then it's totally reasonable to change schools. There's nothing wrong with it.